# Delphi XE6 FireDAC - Export TFDQuery recordset to JSON

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe6, firedac

I'm using FireDAC in Delphi XE6 to query a database (Pervasive) through ODBC.  I have a TFDQuery component which runs my SELECT query and returns the records.  Once the query is complete I want to export the data in the recordset as JSON.  I've tried using the following code :

```
fdacQuery.SaveToStream(myStream, sfJSON);
```

This creates JSON, but only for the table definition i.e. field names, data types, constraints etc. - there is no representation of the data.  Is there another method I should be using to export just the recordset data as JSON?  Is there another solution?

Comment: Have you changed the `ResourceOptions.StoreItems` property ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip - I've now set that property to [siData] which has changed the result but still no data.  I'm now getting the following JSON :

    {"FDBS":{"Version":11,"Manager":{"TableList":[{"class":"Table","Name":"Customers","SourceID":1,"RowList":[]}]}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size then. I did it for a utility I needed yesterday. It uses SuperObject. I left all field types in the code in case you want to add other special treatments or tweak any of those I put in. It's working for me on many random datasets right now.

```
class procedure TTool.ExportDataSetToJson(DataSet: TDataSet; FileName: string; Append: boolean = false);
const
  SData = 'data';
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  item : ISuperObject;
  wasActive: boolean;
  fld : TField;
begin
  json := SO;
  json.O[SData] := SA([]);
  wasActive := DataSet.Active;
  try
    DataSet.Active := true;
    DataSet.First;
    while not DataSet.Eof do
    begin
      item := SO;
      for fld in DataSet.Fields do
      begin
        case fld.DataType of
//          ftUnknown: ;
          ftString,
          ftBlob,
          ftMemo,
          ftFmtMemo,
          ftBytes,
          ftVarBytes,
          ftFixedChar,
          ftFixedWideChar,
          ftWideMemo,
          ftByte,
          ftWideString: item.S[fld.FieldName] := fld.AsString;
          ftBoolean: item.B[fld.FieldName] := fld.AsBoolean;
          ftFloat,
          ftSingle,
          ftExtended,
          ftCurrency,
          ftFMTBcd,
          ftBCD: item.D[fld.FieldName] := fld.AsFloat;
          ftTime : item.S[fld.FieldName] := TimeToJson(fld.AsDateTime);
          ftDate,
          ftTimeStamp,
          ftOraTimeStamp,
          ftDateTime: item.S[fld.FieldName] := DateTimeToJson(fld.AsDateTime);
          ftSmallint,
          ftInteger,
          ftWord,
          ftAutoInc,
          ftLongWord,
          ftShortint,
          ftLargeInt: item.I[fld.FieldName] := fld.AsLargeInt;
//          ftGraphic: ;
//          ftParadoxOle: ;
//          ftDBaseOle: ;
//          ftTypedBinary: ;
//          ftCursor: ;
//          ftADT: ;
//          ftArray: ;
//          ftReference: ;
//          ftDataSet: ;
//          ftOraBlob: ;
//          ftOraClob: ;
//          ftVariant: ;
//          ftInterface: ;
//          ftIDispatch: ;
          ftGuid: item.S[fld.FieldName] := fld.AsString;
//          ftOraInterval: ;
//          ftConnection: ;
//          ftParams: ;
//          ftStream: ;
//          ftTimeStampOffset: ;
//          ftObject: ;
          else
            item.S[fld.FieldName] := fld.AsString;
        end;
      end;
      DataSet.Next;
      json.A[SData].Add(item);
    end;
    if Append then
      TFile.AppendAllText(FileName, json.AsJSon(true, true))
    else
      json.SaveTo(FileName, true, true);
  finally
    DataSet.Active := wasActive;
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the code in the tutorial at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_REST_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application_and_FireDAC yet?

```
// Create dataset list
Result := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
// Add departments dataset
TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, sDepartment, FDQueryDepartment);
// Add employees dataset
TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, sEmployees, FDQueryDepartmentEmployees);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  I have taken a look at that tutorial but I don't think it helps me as the TFDJSONDataSets object returns JSON data with mime encoded binary content.  This means that RAD studio needs to be used at both ends, whereas I want to support all clients and platforms.